# Accessing Clipboard Module via Pyperclip on Python 3.6.1

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#!

PASSWORDS = {'gmail':'TEST123',
             'fb':'TEST1234',     
             'td':'654', 'fwt':'4567'
       }
import sys, pyperclip, clipboard
if len(sys.argv)< 2:
    print('[account]: account password]')
    sys.exit()
account=sys.argv[1]
if account in PASSWORDS:
    pyperclip.copy(PASSWORDS[account])
    print('Password for '+ account + ' copied to clipboard.')
    print(pyperclip.paste())


else:
    print('There is no account named'+account)
```

Hello. An issue I am having at the moment is finding clipboard after copy and pasting pyperclip (and using the module) for a particular block. For this reason, when I call on the code through CMD (using Anaconda), line 12 prints but the password does not. Additionally, if you type py filename.py fb (or whichever key within PASSWORD), I have the condition print that the password has been copied to the clipboard. Are there ways to access clipboard through Anaconda? If not, what other ways can I access it? Thank you in advance.